# Find all smooth solutions of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=g$ for various $g$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

This question comes from *Complex Variables: An Introduction* (pg 226, question 5):

> Find all solutions $f\in\mathscr{E}(\mathbb{C})=\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ to the equation $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=g$ for:
>
> (a): $g(z)=z$
>
> (b): $g(z)=\bar{z}$
>
> (e): $g\in\mathscr{H}(\mathbb{C})$

(I skipped some of the questions)

I'm honestly at a bit of a loss as to how to approach this problem. For (a) and (e), we know such a solution exists by Theorem 3.2.1 (which is the solution to the inhomogeneous Cauchy-Riemann equation, and says that a smooth solution will exist if $g$ is smooth) but how would you classify all (smooth) solutions?

For (b), we can apply $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial {z}}$ to the equation to conclude that $f$ is harmonic, but I'm still at a bit of a loss to reduce the number of solutions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All given $g$ don't involve $\bar z$ very much: it appears to the first power, at most. So it makes sense to look for $f$ of similar form: $$f(z) =  \bar z f_1(z)+\bar z^2 f_2(z)\tag1$$ where $ f_1,f_2$ are holomorphic. (More generally, one could consider $\sum_{n=0}^N \bar z^n f_n(z)$, etc.)

Applying the $\partial/\partial\bar z$ operator to $(1)$ and equating coefficients with the given right hand side
will give you a solution.

Once you have one solution, all other solutions are obtained by adding an arbitrary holomorphic function $f_0$. Indeed, for any two solutions of the inhomogeneous Cauchy-Riemann equation, their difference solve the homogeneous equation, i.e., it is holomorphic.

Comment: Indeed, that was much easier than I was making it out to be. Thank you.